# Dart equivalent of signal.butter

Tags: python, flutter, dart, scipy

I need to port the below python code to dart but I can't seem to find the equivalent to the signal.butter() function.

```
 def pan_tompkins_detector(self, unfiltered_ecg, MWA_name='cumulative'):
        """
        Jiapu Pan and Willis J. Tompkins.
        A Real-Time QRS Detection Algorithm. 
        In: IEEE Transactions on Biomedical Engineering 
        BME-32.3 (1985), pp. 230–236.
        """
        
        maxQRSduration = 0.150 #sec
        f1 = 5/self.fs
        f2 = 15/self.fs

        b, a = signal.butter(1, [f1*2, f2*2], btype='bandpass')

        filtered_ecg = signal.lfilter(b, a, unfiltered_ecg)        

        diff = np.diff(filtered_ecg) 

        squared = diff*diff

        N = int(maxQRSduration*self.fs)
        mwa = MWA_from_name(MWA_name)(squared, N)
        mwa[:int(maxQRSduration*self.fs*2)] = 0

        mwa_peaks = panPeakDetect(mwa, self.fs)

        return mwa_peaks
```

This is what I already came up with:

```
    double maxQRSduration = 0.150;
    int fs = 250;
    double f1 = 5/fs;
    double f2 = 15/fs;
    dynamic b= firwin(3, Array([f1*2, f2*2]), pass_zero: false, fs: 250);
```

The firwin function does not seem to do the job. Are there any other dart packages or functions that are the same as the signal.butter function in python?

Comment: what is `signal.butter`? From what module did you get it?

Comment: @furas https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

Comment: I found this: https://pub.dev/packages/iirjdart - It's not as fully featured as scidart and it's not null safe, but perhaps you can use it just for the butterworth filter. Failing that, you can port iirFilter and butter to scidart and submit a pull request - It looks fairly straightforward to port at first glance